# С++, rotate bmp file

Tags: c++, image, rotation, bmp

I need to rotate a bmp file exactly with 180 degrees. (If possible, do not change anything except the RotateImage function.)

At the moment, from this picture:

[image: Input image]

I get this:

[image: Output image]

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Code:

```
void RotateImage(tagRGBQUAD* RGB, int biSize, FILE* f) {
    int width = 404; // Image width
    int height = 404; // Image height
    fseek(f, 1078, SEEK_SET); // Offset of bitmap data from the header in bytes

    // Create a temporary array to store the pixels
    tagRGBQUAD* temp = new tagRGBQUAD[width * height];

    // Read the image pixels into the temporary array
    fread(temp, sizeof(tagRGBQUAD), width * height, f);

    // Rotate the image 180 degrees without distortion
    for (int y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int index1 = (y * width + x);
            int index2 = ((height - 1) - y) * width + x;

            // Swap pixels
            tagRGBQUAD tempPixel = temp[index1];
            temp[index1] = temp[index2];
            temp[index2] = tempPixel;
        }
    }

    // Write the modified pixels back to the file
    fseek(f, 1078, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(temp, sizeof(tagRGBQUAD), width * height, f);

    delete[] temp;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
BitMapHeader header;
tagRGBQUAD RGBQuad[256];
BYTE c;
FILE* fb;
char filename[] = "sqw.bmp";
int i;
if (!(fb = fopen(filename, "r+b"))) { printf("file not open"); return 1; }

    header = ReadHeader(fb);
    
    RotateImage(RGBQuad, header.biSize + 14, fb);
    
    fclose(fb);
    return 0;

}
```

(most of the code had to be trimmed so that stackoverflow would not give an error)

Comment: Nitpick:  You need to rotate the *image* by 180 degrees, *not the file*.  The `bmp` file has a specific order and rotating the file by 180 degrees will mess up the data format.

Comment: Can you post *plain text* code with minimal `\\` characters.  Most of them are in invalid locations and must be removed before successful compilation.

Comment: The input image is 367x368, not 404x404. More generally, you are hard-coding a bunch of magic numbers in `RotateImage`; it seems those numbers don't actually match the contents of the test .bmp file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Back in the days of actual hard drives, my files rotated a lot more than 180 degrees, with no damage at all. :-)

Comment: I have to ask -- hasn't the "image rotation" issue been solved thousands of times, and especially for Windows bmp files?  I am sure there are thousands of links to actual C++ (or even C) code that show rotation of a bmp file.   There is no need to reinvent this wheel -- it is a matter of getting code that works, and if you want to fix your version, compare a working version to what you wrote.

Comment: I highly recommend using an image library.  See [softwarerecs.se].